# Sprout Reports plugin - How to output a Matrix field into a row

Tags: craft3, matrix, plugins, plugin-sproutreports

I'm not clear on how I would iterate over a Matrix field to be able to include the content in the row.

Wish there was an example in the docs: https://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/docs/reports/custom-twig-template-report.html#template-settings

```
{% for entry in entries %}

    {% do craft.sproutReports.addRow([
      entry.title, 
      entry.myMatrixField
    ]) %}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it to work with this code:

```
{% for entry in entries %}

    {% set myArray = [entry.title] %}

    {% for block in entry.myMatrixField %}

        {% set myArray = myArray|merge([block.field1,block.field2,block.field3]) %}  

    {% endfor %}

    {% do craft.sproutReports.addRow(myArray) %}

{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the below code

```
{% for block in entry.myMatrixField %}
  {% if block.type == "sproutReports" %}
    <blockquote class="sproutReports{{ loop.index }}">
      <p>{{ block.sproutReports}}</p>
    </blockquote>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: My question was specific to Sprout Reports plugin.